# How to hide jQuery Sub-Menus(ddsmoothmenu)?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, master-pages

I'm new to jQuery and i must admit that i've understood nothing yet, the syntax appears to me as an unknown language although i thought that i had my experiences with javascript.
Nevertheless i managed it to implement [this menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm) in my asp.net masterpage's header. 
Even got it to work that the content-page is loaded with ajax with help from [here](http://www.malbecmedia.com/blog/development/coding-a-ajax-site-that-degrades-gracefully-with-jquery/).
But finally i'm failing with the menu to disappear when the new page was loaded asynchronously. I dont know how to hide this accursed jQuery Menu.

Following the part of the js-file where the events are registered for hiding/disappearing. I dont know how to get the part that is responsible for it and even i dont know **how to implement that part in my Anchor-onclick function** where i dont have a reference to the jQuery Object.

```
buildmenu:function($, setting){
 var smoothmenu=ddsmoothmenu
 var $mainmenu=$("#"+setting.mainmenuid+">ul") //reference main menu UL
 $mainmenu.parent().get(0).className=setting.classname || "ddsmoothmenu"
 var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
 $headers.hover(
  function(e){
   $(this).children('a:eq(0)').addClass('selected')
  },
  function(e){
   $(this).children('a:eq(0)').removeClass('selected')
  }
 )
 $headers.each(function(i){ //loop through each LI header
  var $curobj=$(this).css({zIndex: 100-i}) //reference current LI header
  var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)').css({display:'block'})
  $subul.data('timers', {})
  this._dimensions={w:this.offsetWidth, h:this.offsetHeight, subulw:$subul.outerWidth(), subulh:$subul.outerHeight()}
  this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false //is top level header?
  $subul.css({top:this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? this._dimensions.h+"px" : 0})
  $curobj.children("a:eq(0)").css(this.istopheader? {paddingRight: smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[2]} : {}).append( //add arrow images
   '<img src="'+ (this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[1] : smoothmenu.arrowimages.right[1])
   +'" class="' + (this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? smoothmenu.arrowimages.down[0] : smoothmenu.arrowimages.right[0])
   + '" style="border:0;" />'
  )
  if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable){
   this._shadowoffset={x:(this.istopheader?$subul.offset().left+smoothmenu.shadow.offsetx : this._dimensions.w), y:(this.istopheader? $subul.offset().top+smoothmenu.shadow.offsety : $curobj.position().top)} //store this shadow's offsets
   if (this.istopheader)
    $parentshadow=$(document.body)
   else{
    var $parentLi=$curobj.parents("li:eq(0)")
    $parentshadow=$parentLi.get(0).$shadow
   }
   this.$shadow=$('<div class="ddshadow'+(this.istopheader? ' toplevelshadow' : '')+'"></div>').prependTo($parentshadow).css({left:this._shadowoffset.x+'px', top:this._shadowoffset.y+'px'})  //insert shadow DIV and set it to parent node for the next shadow div
  }
  $curobj.hover(
   function(e){
    var $targetul=$subul //reference UL to reveal
    var header=$curobj.get(0) //reference header LI as DOM object
    clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').hidetimer)
    $targetul.data('timers').showtimer=setTimeout(function(){
     header._offsets={left:$curobj.offset().left, top:$curobj.offset().top}
     var menuleft=header.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? 0 : header._dimensions.w
     menuleft=(header._offsets.left+menuleft+header._dimensions.subulw>$(window).width())? (header.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? -header._dimensions.subulw+header._dimensions.w : -header._dimensions.w) : menuleft //calculate this sub menu's offsets from its parent
     if ($targetul.queue().length<=1){ //if 1 or less queued animations
      $targetul.css({left:menuleft+"px", width:header._dimensions.subulw+'px'}).animate({height:'show',opacity:'show'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
      if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable){
       var shadowleft=header.istopheader? $targetul.offset().left+ddsmoothmenu.shadow.offsetx : menuleft
       var shadowtop=header.istopheader?$targetul.offset().top+smoothmenu.shadow.offsety : header._shadowoffset.y
       if (!header.istopheader && ddsmoothmenu.detectwebkit){ //in WebKit browsers, restore shadow's opacity to full
        header.$shadow.css({opacity:1})
       }
       header.$shadow.css({overflow:'', width:header._dimensions.subulw+'px', left:shadowleft+'px', top:shadowtop+'px'}).animate({height:header._dimensions.subulh+'px'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
      }
     }
    }, ddsmoothmenu.showhidedelay.showdelay)
   },
   function(e){
    var $targetul=$subul
    var header=$curobj.get(0)
    clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').showtimer)
    $targetul.data('timers').hidetimer=setTimeout(function(){
     $targetul.animate({height:'hide', opacity:'hide'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.outtime)
     if (smoothmenu.shadow.enable){
      if (ddsmoothmenu.detectwebkit){ //in WebKit browsers, set first child shadow's opacity to 0, as "overflow:hidden" doesn't work in them
       header.$shadow.children('div:eq(0)').css({opacity:0})
      }
      header.$shadow.css({overflow:'hidden'}).animate({height:0}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.outtime)
     }
    }, ddsmoothmenu.showhidedelay.hidedelay)
   }
  ) //end hover
 }) //end $headers.each()
 $mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible'})
}
```

one link of my menu what i want to hide when the content is redirected to another page(i need "closeMenu-function"):

```
<li><a href="DeliveryControl.aspx" onclick="AjaxContent.getContent(this.href);closeMenu();return false;">Delivery Control</a></li>
```

In short: I want to fade out the submenus the same way they do automatically onblur, so that only the headermenu stays visible but i dont know how.

Thanks, Tim

**EDIT**: thanks to Starx' private-lesson in jQuery for beginners i solved it:
I forgot the # in $("#smoothmenu1"). After that it was not difficult to find and call the hover-function from the menu's headers to let them fade out smoothly:

```
$("#smoothmenu1").find("ul").hover();
```

Regards,
Tim

Comment: If you can't understand jQuery, you should learn it or stop using it.  Using a framework that you don't understand is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: "where i dont have a reference to the jQuery Object" - the jQuery object is global, so that makes no sense.

Comment: Tim, not to be harsh, but I have to agree.  It seems you need to take a step back and learn/practice the fundamentals a bit more. After a few practice projects, each isolating a technology, things should all make a lot more sense.

Comment: @Slaks: Youre right. But it looked cool and when you never try you'll never learn. Everybody suggests using jQuery on stackoverflow, so i thought i give it a try ;)

Comment: @Pointy: The Menu Item itself is global, but it has only function for initializing it. My problem is how to get the current object of the submenu or at least to headermenu that i want to hide, because i dont know how to iterate through it.

Comment: @Kervin: i dont want to waste more time for it because its not so important(its only a menu). But its almost managed so i would loose more time to take a differebnt way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I didn't read your whole post. But if you are using a jQuery Menu, that menu should having a container element like `<div>` or `<ul>` and they will either have a class or id

In case it is a id then do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myelementid").hide();
});
```

In case it has a class then do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".myelementclass").hide();
});
```

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

```
$("#mainmenu").children().hide(); // to hide all child elements
```

or

```
$(".submenu").hide(); //to hide every submenu
```

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten that # before and also didnt remember that theres a hide-function for jQuery Objects. My problem is how to get all submenus, so that only the header of the menu stays visible.
The following hides all submenus including the header:
$("#smoothmenu1").find("ul").find("li").hide();

Comment: Your submenu usually have a class, then hide using class selector or I have an updated answer for you

Comment: I finally got it:  $("#smoothmenu1").find("ul").hover();
This made the fade-out effect. Hiding it would cause that the menu will never be visible again apparently, will it?

Thanks for the hint Starx :)